# Backing Out One Folder To Obtain Sourcepath

Tags: java, xml, netbeans

In a program that I am building I have a file which is dependent on an import (import SScomp.EMeasure;). Using build.xml, I am trying to specify that the sourcepath is one folder back. However, while the program will compile and run, I am still getting many errors saying "error: package SScomp does not exist" which refers back to "import SScomp.EMeasure;" 
To be more specific, the build.xml file is located in D:\projects\December\PhaseIV\JELDoclet\build.xml. 
The EMeasure.java file that is needed is located in D:\projects\December\PhaseIV\Library\src\SScomp\EMeasure.java. How can I specify the location of the sourcepath so that I no longer get any errors concerning SScomp.EMeasure?

```
<target name="run" depends="main">
    <javadoc doclet="com.jeldoclet.JELDoclet"
        docletpath="build\jar\jeldoclet.jar"
        sourcefiles="${sourcefiles}"
        sourcepath= "cd..\Library\src\SScomp\*.java"
        destdir="${distmodelnotebook}" 
        additionalparam="-d ${distmodelnotebook} -filename eKAADs.xml -outputEncoding UTF-8 -sourcepath"
        private="yes">
    </javadoc>
</target>
```

Comment: This is nonsense `sourcepath= "cd..\"` ! There is no miraculous searchpath of commands like `cd ..` performs. If you can not get it to work with `sourcepath= "..\Library\src\SScomp\*.java"` you must set the absolut path `sourcepath= "D:\projects\December\PhaseIV\Library\src\SScomp\*.java"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the correct sourcepath I had to use the variable ${basedir} which was in an ant script that I was unaware of. The reason I didn't use a literal path was due to the fact that this program is going to be sent to other people. This means that using a literal path would have caused other users errors.